# Wordpress AWS Error establishing a database connection

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In one of my project, I am getting this error while accessing the website.

When I restarted RDS instance, the problem was solved and website was running.

After 2 days, again I am getting the same error. But after restarting RDS, Problem is solved. I am not able to figure out this problem. Please help.

Comment: did you try after `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);` in wp-config file?

Comment: I have written this in wp-config file. Lets see if error occurs again. Thanks :-)

Comment: Are you using the END POINT of the RDS instance or querying the IP address and then using it ? Please use END POINT which would be in the format abcdef.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 1):

Look at this tutorial, it covers the whole process but you may skip to the last part: [Using Amazon RDS with your WordPress installation](https://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/using-amazon-rds-with-your-wordpress-installation/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with **AWS Lightsail**.

Solved as follows :

- Checking of database instance service, **MariaDB** or **MySql**
  (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lightsail-wordpress-fix-database-errors/):

> `test ! -f "/opt/bitnami/common/bin/openssl" && echo "Approach A" || echo "Approach B"`

> `test -d /opt/bitnami/mariadb && echo "MariaDB" || echo "MySQL"`

- Then, check that WordPress has the right credentials for the `DB_USER` and `DB_PASSWORD` as set from database instance
  (https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-connect-wordpress-to-mysql-managed-database):
- Then, restart the Apache service
  (https://linuxize.com/post/start-stop-restart-apache/)

> `sudo systemctl restart apache2` or `sudo service apache2 restart`